# How updating KMS key for a Redshift cluster affects the databases and schemas?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-cloudformation, amazon-kms

I have a redshift cluster which currently uses AWS KMS default key for encryption. My plan is to use a KMS Customer Managed Key for the cluster encryption. 
Per aws Cloudformation documentation this change would replace the cluster. But it doesn't say how the replacement would exactly be performed?! My question is does redshift keep my databases/schemas and would load data to the new cluster after it replaces it?

Comment: What ever you do, dont forget to create snapshot of your redshift just in case.

Comment: You can encrypt an *unencrypted* cluster, which creates a new encrypted cluster and Redshift will automatically migrate your data to the new cluster. However I'm not sure this will work if your cluster is *already encrypted*. If I were you I'd consider unloading all your data to S3, creating a new cluster with your CMK and then loading the data into it from S3.

Comment: @NathanGriffiths thanks for the comment. We cannot change the encryption key (in my case from aws default key to KMS CMK) if the cluster is already encrypted. So I had to create a new cluster with my own KMS CMK and reload all my data to the cluster.

Comment: @Nisman - This is a side question but how did you reload all the data to the new cluster? Is there any tool or utility or script you used?

Answer (score 0):

We just did the decrypt cluster and then re-encrypt the cluster with a client-managed key and all is well - just took about 2 hours with a fairly small data volume around 50 gb - glad we caught the issue when we wanted to make a portable but secure backup and restore plan between different AWS accounts/from PROD to DEV reimage during code freeze.